# Ensuring installation/filesystem is properly in place

Tags: redhawksdr

I have installed RedHawk 1.10.0 using Ubuntu 14.0.4LTS as described in appendix F of the RedHawk documentation.  I also installed standalone IDE from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/redhawksdr/files/redhawk/1.10.0/el6/x86_64/redhawk-ide-1.10.0.R201407290010-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz/download) 
again, as specified in appendix F, chapter 2.5. The IDE comes up looking ok, but here are the problems:

1. The components list is empty (there are supposed to be a set of pre-defined components). The directory is empty as well on the file system.
2. When attempting to generate C++ component, I get:

   "Exception running "/bin/redhawk-codegen" /bin/redhawk-codegen - template=redhawk.codegen.jinja.cpp.component.pull --checkSupport

In detail, it said: `bin/redhawk-codegen":error=2 no such file or directory`. The `/bin/redhawk-codegen` is there under `OSSIEHOME`. The "pull" template is under:  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redhawk/codegen/jinja/cpp/component`.

3. If I attempt to start Domain Manager I get an error "no domain configuration available".

So for all these problems it is obvious that I need to get a better picture of the expected file layout of all IDE and core RedHawk components.  This is not clear from the documentation. Is there a starting point where I can begin debugging "where to find things"?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first issue:

When installing for CentOS using the RPMs, a number of components, and devices are pre-packaged into the yum repository.  When installing from source, as one must do for Ubuntu in 1.10, the pieces of Redhawk are modular and are installed individually.

The directions from Appendix F walk the user through installing each of the parts that make up the framework.  The core, a GPP, bulkio, bustio, and the code generator.  This does not include any components or devices (other than the GPP).  To install these, you'll need to clone them from their respective git repositories and build and install from source either from the command line, or through the REDHAWK IDE.  Building and installing the components from the command line follows the same pattern as the framework, there is a reconf script, which creates the configure script which creates the makefile script.  eg. ./reconf; ./configure; make; sudo make install

Regarding your second issue:

These symptoms seem to point to the OSSIEHOME and SDRROOT variables not being set.  Make sure that the OSSIEHOME and SDRROOT variables are set in the terminal using "echo $SDRROOT" and "echo $OSSIEHOME" prior to running the IDE.  Keep in mind that the environments are unique to each session so, for example, having them set in one bash terminal does not guarantee they are set when launching the IDE from a desktop shortcut.  Confirm they are set in your terminal, then launch the IDE from the same terminal.

Regarding your last issue:

This is likely also caused by your second issue.  However, if it is not resolved following the above steps, take a look within $SDRROOT/dom/domain  There should be two files.  One DomainManager.dmd.xml.template and one DomainManager.dmd.xml.  If all you have is the template then you need to create the DomainManager.dmd.xml file by copying the template.  Then edit it and fill in the id and name fields.  The default name is generally REDHAWK_DEV and the id should be a UUID.

Comment: Youssef - thanks for the suggestions - it seems that although the SDRROOT and OSSIEHOME were set properly, the IDE does not seem to evaluate them correctly when establishing its working directories.  I reinstalled using the CentOS version and all of this went away.  Also the missing base components are all included in the CentOS package so I did not have to get them specifically.